# Git does not wait for user input when gvim is set as the default editor

Tags: git, vim

In my gitconfig, I set gvim as the default editor.

If I do git commit, the editor opens, with the expected content, but the git terminal command has already exited with "Aborting due to empty commit message" - i.e., it did not wait for a response from gvim before continuing.

Similarly, if I run git rebase -i, it opens gvim, but this time the file is empty, and the rebase proceeds non-interactively in the background.

In both cases, if I set the editor to vim, rather than gvim, everything works as expected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bvim%5D+gvim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `gvim` forks into the background and detaches from the terminal.  The parent process, the one that was originally spawned, exits almost immediately.

Git has no way of knowing when your editor is done except to know when it exits.  If the process it spawned exits promptly, it thinks you're done editing, and since you haven't saved anything, it reads the file as it is at that point and aborts your commit.

If you want to use `gvim`, set the editor value to `gvim -f`.  The `-f` option prevents the editor from forking, so it persists until you exit, just like a terminal `vim` does.  This is also a good idea if you want to set the `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` environment variables for other reasons; these variables are interpreted by the shell, so you can pass arguments to them like I mentioned above.